# Creating Variables via String Inputs

Tags: r

I am trying to create a loop that generates variables. But I need a way to name the variables using an input method. What is the convention for inputting string names in variable generating

x="Variable"
y="weight"
z="height"

xy=paste(x,y,sep="")
xz=paste(x,y,sep="")

xy_one=1:10
xy_two=11:20

So xy_one should be named VariableWeight_one
and xz_two should be names Variableheight_two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Carl not to do it that way but I think his approach could be improved by using "[[" rather than "$". Try:

```
myVars<-list()
x="Variable"; y="Weight"; z="Height"
myVars[[ paste(x,y,"_one", sep="")]] <- 1:10
myVars[[ paste(x,z,"_one", sep="")]] <- 11:20
```

If you really still want to construct names I'll compose a suitable addition:

```
 x="Variable"; y="Weight"; z="Height"
 assign( paste(x,y,"_one", sep=""),  1:10)
 assign( paste(x,z,"_one", sep=""), 11:20)
 ls(patt="Variable")
[1] "VariableHeight_one" "VariableWeight_one"
```

Compare the effort (and language circumlocutions) it might take to find the first variable you created using your approach with with how simple it would be to extract the first element from myVars:

```
 eval(parse( text=ls(patt="Variable")[1] ))
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

  myVars[[1]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

(Furthermore, it wasn't even the right one.)

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is: don't do it that way.  It's much easier, and more productive, to create a `list` or `dataframe` variable, dump your data into elements of same, and then assign names to these elements.   In your case,

```
mydata<- list()
mydata$VariableWeight_one <- xy_one
mydata$Variableheight_two <- xy_two
```

Comment: Thank you for the repsonse Carl. But at the end of the day, I am trying to create a way to generate variables throughout a loop. I need the convention used in R to input strings into variables names.

Comment: for (i in c("abe","john","ryan","carl") {i_score=i}

Comment: @jessica then you'll have to look into the infamous `eval(parse(foo))` construct -- or DWin's  `assign()` method.